# Выбор текстового документа

Tags: c#

Есть вот такой код(2), я бы хотел при нажатии кнопки выбрать .txt, а после выполнить вот этот код (1), с указанным текстовым документом ранее.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string str = string.Empty;
            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"D:\test.txt"))
            {
                str = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            str = str.Replace("1", "2");            

             using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\test.txt"))
             {
                 file.Write(str);
             }
        }
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp12
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А проблема какая?

Comment: Не знаю, как подключить выбор текстового документа и код

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не даёт открыть файл через OpenFileDialog](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665506/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-openfiledialog)

Comment: [Посмотрите тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665506/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-openfiledialog) или [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так откроется диалоговое окно, и можно будет вручную выбрать файл:

```
OpenFileDialog OpenFileCSV = new OpenFileDialog();
if (OpenFileCSV.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //выполнить Ваш код;
}
```